# How to dynamically add edittext to android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to add edittext dynamically to the android display. I want to make something like in the android contacts where you can dynamically add fields and remove them if you dont need them.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Everything dynamically

```
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("TaskID");
        TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
        task=new EditText(this);
        task.setMaxWidth(100);
        task.setMinHeight(100);
        tv1.setText("Task");
        id=new EditText(this);
        id.setMaxHeight(10);
        TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
        name=new EditText(this);

        name.setMaxHeight(1);
        tv2.setText("Name");


        LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(this);
        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
         setContentView(l);


         l.addView(tv);
         l.addView(id);

        l.addView(tv1);
        l.addView(task);
        l.addView(tv2);
```

Comment: if your setContentView uses a layout from xml file then you can add in that layout.In these example i created a layout,set it as contentViw and added view on that layout